# Informal way to address a woman (who you do not know) in the UK?

Tags: slang

When addressing a man informally I tend to use "mate" or "my friend" however it has never been clear to me how to address a woman.  In London, where I live "dear", "luv" or "darlin" seem to be used frequently but I am not a fan of any of them.  I therefore don't use any term unless I happen to know the woman's name.

I quite like the way "lady" is used in the US so perhaps that is an option.

Any suggestions and what terms do you use(if any)?

Comment: Probably a better fit on Interpersonal Skills.SE. I usually avoid the vocative (address), and either make a fairly obvious statement (British weather is so obliging) or hedge a request (for information, usually, back in the days when getting lost was an option) "Excuse me, ...".

Comment: Opinion based CV. I agree with Edwin. Avoid vocative address. Many women find being addressed as  e.g. sweetheart, dear, love, darling, honey, etc, by male strangers very annoying. I myself don't much like being called 'mate'. I feel like saying to baristas, bus drivers, etc, 'I'm not your bloody mate!'. I especially hate being addressed as 'bud'.

Comment: I use *you* or a proper name. Any other terms may offend with their false friendship or patronising nature. Only once some modest degree of intimacy has been achieved would I move on to *dear*, *midear*, *ducks* or *hen* and the many alternatives.